# Using sub directories for models (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, models

I have to use 3 databases for a project with regretably similar names for tables. I thought I would place them in sub directories so I created one under App called xmaster and place my models in there. To try my idea I have one - Section.

I thought then I should be able to reference it simply by amending the path in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('XProducts/Builder', function()
{ $section = new App\xmaster\Section(); 
  $sections = $section->with('sectionType'); 
return view('xmaster.builder.sections',['sections'=>$sections]); })->name('builderfront');
```

but I get an

```
Class 'App\xmaster\Section' not found
```

error, even if I add

```
uses App\xmaster\Section
```

Comment: What is the namespace you have used in App\xmaster\Section class?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to amend the namespace at the top of the model to

> namespace App\xmaster;